# boosting according to user preferences in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm currently working on a targeted ads system.
I keep track of users preferences and I'm supposed to retrieve ads accordingly.
I index ads using **elasticsearch** in which I index the tags of the ad:

> curl -XPUT localhost:9200/ads/ad/ad789 -d '{
>       "tags" : [ "sports", "gaming" ]
>       }'

**Now here comes the tricky part**,
I want to boost the ads that have the tag sports by 8 and gaming by 2 according to the user's
preferences.

Comment: What have you tried? I'd have a look at the [function_score query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Comment: it is used to boost documents retrieved by a query, what i need is boost multiple parts of the query with the same attribute searched "tags"

Comment: Sure, but your documents might match different queries or filters right? You can also have multiple queries combined together and assign a different `boost` to each of them, without using the function_score.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set up a `function_score` query with multiple filters, where each filter contributes a different boost if it matches.  For example, this query will multiply the document score by 8 if it has a "sports" tag, and by 2 if it contains a "games" tag.

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "tags": "sports"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 8
        },
        {
          "filter": {
            "term": {
              "tags": "games"
            }
          },
          "boost_factor": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

By default, the boost value will be multiplied with the query score.  Alternatively, you could use the `boost_mode` parameter to use only the function score instead (replace), add the function score to the query score (sum), average the function score and query score (average), or use the max/min of function score or query score (max, min).

See the [function_score documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) for more details.